# Meaning of song's chorus "Shudder to think"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm trying to understand meaning of chorus of the song "Tegan And Sara - Shudder to think". It goes: "Shudder to think that I'd find my company off on standby". I'm interested in second part of this sentence. I knew what "on standby" means. I tried to google "company off", "off on standby" in case it's some idiom but I found nothing. So please explain me what does "my company off on standby" means.

Comment: The words ***company off*** aren't syntactically related in this context. The basic underlying statement is *My company is **on standby***, where the highlighted adverbial element just means ***ready** [to act upon orders]*. But there's nothing wrong with introducing that *second* preposition ***off***, which implies spomething along the lines of ***away** [from where the speaker is]*. You'll see the same usage in contexts like *We're going off on holiday tomorrow* - where again, ***off*** is optional, equivalent to the alternative possibility *...going **away** on holiday*.

Comment: ...by the way, I'm a native speaker with a degree in literature, but ***I*** don't know what "my company is [off] on standby" means. Feasibly it's somehow related to usages like *My TV is on standby*, but that doesn't seem likely given ***off*** (because TV's don't physically move). But I can't tell whether ***my company*** is some sort of metaphorical reference to ***the people in my military unit / under my command***, or an unusual way of saying ***my companionship***. Not really a text for learners to spend time on, I suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I had to look up the lyrics to the song as I haven't heard it, but it looks like the whole song is about considering life without your love being reflected back to you.

"Off on standby" in this case reads to me like switching a TV off by the button on the remote control. It's no longer on for you, but it is "waiting" to be turned back on. So if your companion is turned off on standby to you, you are in the heart-rending situation where they are no longer responding to you, but could potentially be turned on by someone else.

Comment: Wow, it's very interesting metaphor!

Comment: Isn't it just! I'm not saying that's the definitive meaning, mind - but I do feel that's what they were after.